# How to enable file and directory indexing in puppet

Tags: apache, vagrant, puphpet

I don't know how to enable directory indexing for apache virtual host in puphpet.
I have localhost defined in `config.yaml` like the following. Indexes doesn't seem to work.

```
vhosts:
    Ow3JtQyukTBm:
        servername: localhost
        serveraliases:
            - localhost
        docroot: /var/www/
        port: '80'
        override:
            - All
        options:
            - Indexes
            - FollowSymLinks
            - MultiViews
        engine: php
        custom_fragment: ''
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_chain: ''
        ssl_certs_dir: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your vhost configuration "directoryindex" with proper paths.

```
directoryindex: /dir_to_index/
```

According to puppet appache documentation https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache:

> Directoryindex:
>
> Sets the list of resources to look for when a client requests an index of the directory by specifying a '/' at the end of the directory name. DirectoryIndex has more information. Defaults to 'undef'.